# Colorize STDIN in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, interactive, ansi-colors

How can I colorize the input (STDIN/the feedback for what I type) in zsh outside the zsh command line?

As a Reference, this is what I want to do with the input:
http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Zsh#Colorize_STDERR

Coloring STDOUT instead of STDIN while setting the Terminal color is not really an option, because it would make blacklisting applications (ncurses stuff: emacs, irssi, ...) much harder.

Comment: Are you asking how to type in colors on the command line? I doubt that zsh will interpret ANSI escape codes in your input and colorize your text as you type it. If you just want your input to be a solid color, you could put the escape code for that color at the end of your $PS1 variable.

Comment: PS1 only sets the color for the zsh command line. I want to colorize my output globally.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say you want to colorize stdin. You can't colorize your input. Do you want the output of all commands to be in a certain color? In that case, you'll need to change the default text color in your terminal program.

Comment: Changing the terminal program's text color would colorize all text, not just the echoed input. However, as a workaround I could change the color and then instead colorize stdout. - I edited my question to give a reference what I'm aiming at.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now, but I don't know how to do that. I put an answer that's the closest I could get...

Comment: This feature request is perfectly reasonable. Modern shells have a little text editor built in for typing commands, recalling history, etc. This little text editor could support syntax coloring, like its bigger cousins.

Comment: Actually there is syntax highlighting, but it only affects the command line of zsh, not _everything else_: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to change stdin, but this will make stdout green and stderr red:

```
exec 1>>(while read line; do
  print '\e[92m'${(q)line}'\e[0m' > /dev/tty; print -n $'\0'; done &)
exec 2>>(while read line; do
  print '\e[91m'${(q)line}'\e[0m' > /dev/tty; print -n $'\0'; done &)
```

1 above refers to stdout (`exec 1>>`...), and 2 refers to stderr. 0 would be for stdin, but the above lines don't seem to do anything if you start them with `exec 0>>`.

I guess if you want to change stdin, you can change your terminal color to whatever you want to use for stdin, and then use something like the above commands to change stderr and stdout to something else...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have played around a bit with the code. I could probably do this by echoing the input myself and redirectiong it to a zsh instance with a fifo: `zsh < /tmp/zshin &  stty -echo; while read -rk c; do print -n "${CYAN}"${(q)c}"${RESET_COLOR}"; print -n ${c} > /tmp/zshin; done`, but thats too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: the input to programs goes directly to the terminal (tty), the input is echoed on the terminal without zsh knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it without piping the output through another process. One possibility was the zsh version posted by yellowantphil. There are other tools out there that are easier to use, though, including but not limited to [regex-markup](http://www.nongnu.org/regex-markup/), [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/) and [swatch](http://swatch.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The [fish shell](http://fishshell.com) could interest you, it has syntax highlighting on command line when you type, but i don't consider it as a stable shell (some basic errors i saw last year and still a few users) and it doesn't respect well known conventions (like `$?` for return code).

Answer (score 0):

If ZSH has a DEBUG signal sent before each command is executed (BASH does this), you can achieve the desired effect by adding escape sequences at the end of your `PS1` variable and resetting it to its default value just before the output is displayed by trapping Bash's `DEBUG` signal.

For instance, try to add `\[\e[1m\e[3m\e[93m\]` (i.e. bold, italic, yellow) at the end of your `PS1` variable and then run `trap 'tput sgr0' DEBUG` and see if it works.

Here's a screenshot from my terminal:
[image: bold, italic and yellow commands]